# is this patent ep1020784a2 expired?

Tags: expired-patent

I am doing patent search first time and struggling to establish if ep1020784a2 patent is withdrawn or expired?

would appreciate feedback from anyone experienced out there.

regards
Kamesh

Answer (score 1):

Application has been deemed withdrawn since 2004 according to EP Register: https://register.epo.org/application?lng=en&number=EP00300235

Comment: however Just for your info its family patent is granted in United Kingdom (GB2345749)